# Why this PUT request is failing with unexpected EOF on google container engine while it works locally?

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, spring-data-rest, google-kubernetes-engine

**EDIT: added status code received on client**

**EDIT 2: The issue seems to be random in nature and when it occurs it seems to affect particular networks at a time only. Recently a team member in a different country faced the issue while at the same time it is working without issue from my own network. Earlier I was facing the issue on my network while I was able to run the same call via curl after ssh'ing into a cloud server.**

**EDIT 3: The issue is happening on requests other than PUT too**

I have Spring Boot based REST API implementation that is giving a strange issue when deployed on Google Container Engine. Some key points about the issue:

1. Works locally on embedded tomcat without any issue.
2. On container engine, the issue is happening only on Http `PUT` request. If I change the method to `PATCH` the error goes away.
3. I have another application with same stack deployed on container engine for several months, and never faced this issue on that application.
4. At client I receive `504 Gateway Timeout` after some delay, which seems to suggest that loadbalancer was waiting for webserver's response while webserver was still waiting for whole request to arrive.

I suspect that I am hitting a bug in load balancing/network layer of GKE.

Following is the exception trace generated by spring:

```
2016-10-03 11:56:51.067 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestExceptionHandler : Could not read an object of type class com.mycompany.Incident from the request!; nested exception is java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket

org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read an object of type class com.mycompany.Incident from the request!; nested exception is java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.readPutForUpdate(PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:220) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.read(PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:186) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:138) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:651) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_102]
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:747) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.access$400(Http11InputBuffer.java:38) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:1073) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:100) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:303) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:511) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:318) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.checkEof(ByteChunk.java:397) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:379) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:338) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar!/:8.5.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.ensureLoaded(ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.java:517) ~[jackson-core-2.8.1.jar!/:2.8.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.detectEncoding(ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.java:126) ~[jackson-core-2.8.1.jar!/:2.8.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.constructParser(ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.java:243) ~[jackson-core-2.8.1.jar!/:2.8.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory._createParser(JsonFactory.java:1271) ~[jackson-core-2.8.1.jar!/:2.8.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createParser(JsonFactory.java:810) ~[jackson-core-2.8.1.jar!/:2.8.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:2312) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.1.jar!/:2.8.1]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.readPutForUpdate(PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:215) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    ... 88 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Hard to really say without looking at what the client is doing, all the stacktrace tells you is that the connection was severed for some reason.

Comment: @Magnus added some more details about client. Please check

Comment: Strange, you could see if there is anything useful in the [load balancer logs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#logging) and enable trace request logging to see where you stop getting the request.

Answer (score 0):

`PUT` HTTP requests typically update an entire resource, whereas `PATCH` HTTP requests typical update *part* of a resource. The implication is that one has more overhead than the other. I have seen 504s before and the root cause was a connection *timeout* on the *backend server*. So if your `PUT` request is taking too long to complete, this could be a possible explanation for your timeout occurring. Your `PATCH` requests probably complete quicker since they're doing less work and thus don't timeout. Try increasing the timeout on the *backend server* if you can.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The `PUT` body is very small json text. Server json parser is getting EOF while reading the request body, so it has actually not started executing the actual business logic yet. The exception trace shows that server-side code was still reading in the request body when it got EOF

Comment: Is there any networking equipment in between that could be severing the connection?

Comment: Yes, google cloud platform loadbalancer. At client I receive 504 Gateway Timeout after some delay, which seems to suggest that loadbalancer was waiting for webserver's response while webserver was still waiting for whole request to arrive.

Comment: Is it possible to bypass the load balancer altogether and hit the server directly? Does the issue remain when doing so?

Comment: I ssh'd into the one of the machine in the cluster and ran the same request using (using LB IP) through curl and it worked without error.